# Riff on Sequential Criterion for Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, metric-spaces

A function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ on a metric space $(X,d)$ is continuous at $p\in X$ if and only if whenever we have a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq X\setminus\{p\}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow p$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(p)$. For my own curiosity, I asked myself whether a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous provided it satisfies the following weaker condition: whenever we have a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq ([a,b]\setminus\{p\})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow p$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(p)$. After playing with examples like Thomas’s function and it’s variants, I have been unable to find a counterexample as the point $p$ is not required to be a rational number. At the same time, when I try to prove $f$ is continuous, I am unable to do so. Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $p\in[a,b]$ and let $x_n\in\cap[a,b]$ such that $x_n\to p$.
We need to show that $f(x_n)\to f(p)$. Choose for $x_n$ a sequence $q^n_k\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]$ such that $q^n_k\to x_n$ for $k\to\infty$. Thus, $f(q^n_k)\to f(x_n)$.

Now choose $k(n)$ such that $|f(q^n_{k(n)})-f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $|q^n_{k(n)}-x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Let now $p_n=q^{n}_{k(n)}$, then we have a sequence
$p_n\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ such that $p_n\to p$, $|f(p_n)-f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(p_n)\to f(p)$. Thus (by triangle inequality), we have $f(x_n)\to f(p)$. Hence, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 6):

More generally, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces with $Y$ regular and $Q\subseteq X$ is dense.  Then if $f:X\to Y$ is a function whose restriction to $Q\cup\{x\}$ is continuous for each $x\in X$, then $f$ is continuous.

To prove this, suppose $U\subseteq Y$ is open and $x\in X$ is such that $f(x)\in U$; we must show that $f(y)\in U$ for all $y$ in some neighborhood of $x$.  By regularity, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ whose closure is contained in $U$.  By continuity of $f$ on $Q\cup \{x\}$ there is an open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $f(y)\in V$ for all $y\in W\cap Q$.  For arbitrary $y\in W$ continuity of $f$ on $Q\cup \{y\}$ now implies that $f(y)\in \overline{V}\subseteq U$.  Thus $W$ is our desired neighborhood of $x$.